# "error loading results file - see log file " in j meter

Tags: linux, testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm running J meter in non-GUI mode and the result file is saving in .jtl format but while browsing the result file in  Jmeter. Getting error

> Error loading Results file -see logfile

In log file few results are executed with HTTP response 200 but few results are

> Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException, Non HTTP response message

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about "seeing the log file"?

There is [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) in the folder where you launch JMeter from, it should contain some information or at least a clue regarding the reason for .jtl file loading failure. If it doesn't - you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

If you run your test using one JMeter instance and using another JMeter instance for results analysis it might be the case there are mismatches in the [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) or if there are different JMeter versions - the result format may be different due to some [incompatible changes.](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html)

Also check your .jtl file, if it' incomplete - you will need to either re-run your test or delete the last line of the .jtl file in case it doesn't have all the columns properly filled in.